# jQuery Colorbox: AJAX content works fine on localhost; not on remote server

Tags: jquery, fancybox, colorbox, facebox

I'm using the [Colorbox lightbox plugin](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/) to display lightboxes with "Outside HTML (Ajax)" on my page.  I'm using all defaults from "Example One" (from the website).

Trouble is, the lightbox works flawlessly on my localhost machine, but displays an endless loading graphic when I try it on my remote server.

The page I'm trying to load is in the same directory as the page I'm calling it from, and both are in a folder one level deep from my web root, on my remote server.  The path names are all relative.

Now, I know the remote page is **loading** the remote page, since I can see the XHR request using Safari's Developer panel, and it has all the content of the ajax page in there; Colorbox just isn't displaying it on the page.

As far as I can tell, both my remote server and localhost machine are running the same hosting environment (Apache 2).

Anyone have any ideas as to why it wouldn't be working on my remote server but working fine on my local machine?

PS - For what it's worth, I ran into the same problem using [FancyBox](http://fancybox.net/) & [FaceBox](https://github.com/defunkt/facebox)

Comment: Are you loading information from the same domain?

Comment: Yes, I am. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check that the page you are fetching is an HTML fragment, not a normal page with <html>, <head> and everything else. ColorBox would probably choke on a full page.

---

e.g. check the source of the [example page](http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/content/ajax.html) used on the official Colorbox site.

Comment: I tried this already, and I get the same problem.  Safari's Developer Panel confirms that it's only loading the fragment, too, but still no joy in the Colorbox itself. Anything else?

Comment: In this case you'll need to check for conflicts between Colorbox and your own code. Can't really help you with that, though. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Is it trying to load AJAX content from a domain that is different from the domain that your site is hosted on? If so, you might be running into cross-domain XHR issues.

Comment: I'm loading content from the same domain (from the same host in the same folder). As I mentioned in my post, I believe the XHR request is functioning, since I can see the loaded content in the Developer panel, just not in the lightbox.